# Getting Your connection is not secure with marionette firefox selenium 3.0 grid

Tags: java, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have updated the web driver to selenium 3.0.1
When i use firefox browser and try to open the https website I get Your connection is not secure exception.
With selenium 2.53.1 web driver below code was working fine.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", "true");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubUrl), caps);
```

As selenium 3.0.1 uses marionette to run latest firefox browsers i tried below 2 code. but both did work

1.

```
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("acceptSslCerts", "true");
        caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        caps.setCapability("marionette", true);
        caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubUrl), caps);
```

2.

```
        caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        caps.setCapability("marionette", true);
        caps.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", "true")
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubUrl), caps);
```

Here is the screenshot
[image: Your connection is not secure error]

Anyone tried to access https websites using seleniumGrid/selenium 3.0/marionette
Can someone point-out how to overcome this issue. I have multiple selenium grids with 20+nodes. Installing the certificate on each is not feasible. I this we need a proper solution to this when used.
Thanks
Shankar KC

Comment: Hi all can i get some pointers here?